# Moving Spam to Spam folder ( postfix-courier imap, spamassassin)

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis, courier, courier-imap

I've a mail server  that supports  virtual-users on mysql with ( courier-imap , postfix , spamassassin, amavis)

For every new user my server creats dirs like (inbox, drafts, sent, trash)
In /home/vmail/username

- First iwant the server automatically create a spam or junk folder for every new user because it dont create it by default
- Second i want to move the mail marked as spam by spamassassin to the users spam or junk folder

I don't have any clues how to do so

Thanks, in advance

Comment: Have seen this question over at Stackoverflow?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470349

Comment: That's for dovcot i'm using courier